# Understanding Parallel Execution of chained CompletableFutures

Tags: java, concurrency, java-stream, threadpool, completable-future

I have a question about how Java Streams and chained CompletableFutures perform.

My question is this: if I run the following code, calling `execute()` with 10 items in the list takes ~11 seconds to complete (number of items in the list plus 1).  This is because I have two threads working in parallel: the first executes the `digItUp` operation, and once that's complete, the second executes the `fillItBackIn` operation, and the first starts processing `digItUp` on the next item in the list.

If I comment out line 36 (`.collect(Collectors.toList())`), the `execute()` method takes ~20 seconds to complete.  The threads do not operate in parallel; for each item in the list, the `digItUp` operation completes, and then the `fillItBackIn` operation completes in sequence before the next item in the list is processed.

It's unclear to me why the exclusion of (`.collect(Collectors.toList())`) should change this behavior.  Can someone explain?

The complete class:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SimpleExample {

    private final ExecutorService diggingThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    private final ExecutorService fillingThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public SimpleExample() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> holesToDig = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            holesToDig.add(random.nextDouble(1000));
        }
        new SimpleExample().execute(holesToDig);
    }

    public void execute(List<Double> holeVolumes) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        holeVolumes.stream()
                .map(volume -> {
                    CompletableFuture<Double> digItUpCF = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> digItUp(volume), diggingThreadPool);
                    return digItUpCF.thenApplyAsync(volumeDugUp -> fillItBackIn(volumeDugUp), fillingThreadPool);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(cf -> {
                    Double volume = cf.join();
                    System.out.println("Dug a hole and filled it back in.  Net volume: " + volume);
                });
        System.out.println("Dug up and filled back in " + holeVolumes.size() + " holes in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
    }

    public Double digItUp(Double volume) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Dug hole with volume " + volume);
        return volume;
    }

    public Double fillItBackIn(Double volumeDugUp) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        System.out.println("Filled back in hole of volume " + volumeDugUp);
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `collect(Collectors.toList())` is a terminal operation, hence it triggers the stream pipeline (remember that streams are evaluated lazily). So when you call `collect`, all of the `CompletableFuture` instances are constructed and placed in the list. This means that there is a chain of `CompletableFuture`, where each one is in turn a chain composed of two stages, let's call them X and Y.

Every time the first thread executor finishes an X stage, it is free to process the X stage of the next composed `CompletableFuture`, while the other thread executor is processing stage Y of the previous `CompletableFuture`. This is the result that we intuitively expect.

On the other hand, when you don't call `collect`, then `forEach` is in this case the terminal operation. However, in this case every element in the stream is processed ***sequentially*** (to confirm try switching to `parallelStream()`), hence stages X and Y get executed for the first `CompletableFuture`. Only when stage Y from the previous stream element is finished, will `forEach` move to the second element in the stream pipeline, and only then will a new `CompletableFuture` be mapped from the original `Double` value.

Comment: M A, thanks for this explanation.  How would I do something like this on an infinite stream of data, where I can't `collect` it?  This could be something like a stream of stock quotes.

Comment: @Mark you can't, by design.

Answer (score 1):

Love this question and M A's answer is awesome! I had a similar use case, and I was using Rxjava there. It worked very well, but my colleagues challenged me to implement it without that. T.T

I tested your example and found a workaround to make it the same performance without `collect`. The trick is to let the `cf.join()` be executed in another thread.

```
.forEach(cf -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(cf::join, anotherThreadpool) 
// another threadpool for the join, or you can omit it, using the default forkjoinpool.commonpool
              .thenAccept(v ->  System.out.println("Dug a hole and filled it back in.  Net volume: " + v))
);
```

But I have to say, this might lead to potential issues as it lacks the support for backpressure...if the upstream is infinite and fast, but the consumer is too slow, all the fast-created `CompletableFuture` in the `map` operator would be accumulated and submitted to the first diggingThreadPool, finally causing RejectedExecutionException, OOM, etc.